# creating xml from database

Tags: xml, salesforce

I am creating an xml from salesforce database, Everything works fine except when there is a & in the data which is been fetched.

```
<apex:page contenttype="text/xml" 
> controller="Test2ab" >  <data
> wiki-section="Timeline"> <apex:repeat
> value="{!lsttask}" var="e" > <event
> start="{!e.ActivityDate}" title=
> "{!e.Subject}"> <apex:outputText
> value="{!e.Subject}" /> </event>
> </apex:repeat> </data></apex:page>
```

and in the controller i am just querying

```
>  lsttask   =[Select OwnerId,WhoId,Status,Subject,ActivityDate from Task where Status = 'Completed' Order By ActivityDate Desc];
```

How can i use an escape for the value retrieved from the database
Thanks
Prady

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know very little about APEX/Salesforce but as you're building an XML from strings fetched from the database you probably need to call the replace method of the string:

```
string.replace("&","&amp;")
```

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/salesforce_apex_language_reference.pdf

you might also want top look at replacing `< with &lt;, > with &gt;,' with  &apos; and " with &quot;`

Answer (score 0):

In your example, this works well:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!HTMLENCODE(e.Subject)}" escape="false" />
```

In simpler cases you can also use:

```
{!HTMLENCODE(e.Subject)}
```

Here is a summary of [HTMLENCODE and other Salesforce functions](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_functions.htm)
An example of pairing apex:outputText with HTMLENCODE and escape=false is in the [Apex Dev Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/salesforce_apex_language_reference.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

This might help as well.  I realize it's late to the game, but it may help others that visit this topic.

http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/anything-worth-doing/a-better-way-to-generate-xml-on-salesforce-using-visualforce-55433